# Click to Deploy Wordpress, Unable to "Allow HTTP traffic"

Tags: wordpress, google-cloud-storage, google-compute-engine

I'm a new user, trying to use "**Click to Deploy**" for Wordpress.

The next instruction is to click on the IP address for your server and follow the instructions to Allow HTTP traffic.

However, when I go to Compute > Compute Engine > VM Instances

...**when I try to click on the IP Address in the EXTERNAL IP column, it has no function.**

### Information from the install:

"Your Wordpress server has been deployed
Deployment information

Zone: us-central1-a
Machine Type: g1-small
Image: debian-7-wheezy-v20140926
Wordpress Version: 4.1
phpMyAdmin Installed: true
What to do next:

To open the HTTP port to your server:
Find your server in the Compute Engine Instance List
Click on the IP address for your server and follow the instructions to Allow HTTP traffic
The HTTP port will not be accessible until this step is completed
Set up Wordpress by navigating to this IP address with your browser

### Access phpMyAdmin at your external IP address appended with /phpmyadmin"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree that the instruction provided by the Developers Console is not very accurate.

What you need to do in order to allow HTTP traffic and be able to access to your fresh instance is:

1. Go to Compute > Compute Engine > VM Instances > wordpress instance. This should match the following regular expression: `wordpress-([a-z\d]){4}`.
2. Click the 'Allow HTTP traffic' checkbox.
3. Click on the external IP address and you should be redirected to: `<external IP address>/wp-admin/install.php`.

Comment: That was far too easy, I feel silly for not finding it earlier.  Thank you very much.